# How to check if there is a relationship between two nodes in a single DB transaction/Query?

Tags: neo4j

I am using Java and would like to check if a relationship between two nodes exists and if so to retrieve the edge weights.
Is there a way to do it in one database call?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In this case "variable length match" r becomes a collection of rels, instead of the usual single relationship.

```
start n1=node(1), n2=node(2)
match shortestPath(n1-[r*]-n2)
return extract(rel in r : r.weight)
```